# What's the recommended way for clocking and archiving with org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I recently started clocking my tasks with org-mode and it's great. I now know how much time I spend on each project I am working on. Each project has multiple subtasks, but by setting "maxlevel:1" I can have a project level report.

I like to clean up my org file regularly by archiving the done tasks. However, it seems clock reports in org-mode consider archived tasks to be from separate projects. Even if I have two archived tasks from the same project they appear in the clock table as two projects (because the structure is duplicated in the archive every time I archive a task).

What is the recommended way to handle this? Ideally I would like to still archive tasks but create a clock report that combines the info from the my files with the archive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [including archives in org-mode clock-table](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21388/including-archives-in-org-mode-clock-table)